# Run applet from jar in Angular 10

Tags: java, html, angular, applet

I have to run a Java applet from his jar in an Angular 10 application, I've tried to run on Chrome, IE11 and Edge but all my tries did not work.

I've done the following things:

- put the jar file inside the Angular folder of my component (with the html, scss and ts files of the component);
  I've added, in the html file, both this:

  ```
  <script language="Javascript">

    var _app = navigator.appName;

    if (_app == 'Mozilla') {
      document.write('<embed code="MyClass.class"',
        'width="200"',
        'height="200"',
        'type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.8.0">');
    }
    else if (_app == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
      document.write('<OBJECT ',
        'classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"',
        'width="200"',
        'height="200">',
        '<PARAM name="code" value="MyClass.class">',
        '</OBJECT>');
    }
    else {
      document.write('<p>Sorry, unsupported browser.</p>');
    }

  </script>
  ```

and this:

```
<object
  codetype="application/java" classid="java:TableManager.class"
  classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
  archive="my_jar.jar" width="740" height="400">
  <param name="code" value="MyClass.class">
</object>
```

and this:

```
<applet code="MyClass.class" archive="my_jar.jar" type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550"></applet>
```

But nothing worked, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Any helpful output in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing, just this once in IE: "The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337"

Answer (score 1):

Many modern web browsers don't support Java applets at all anymore, and those that do require the user to explicitly enable support.

Why?  Because Java plugins for web browsers were notorious for security flaws that put the user of risk of having their computer hacked via a malicious applet.

My recommendation is that you change your application architecture to avoid any need of running Java in the user's browser.

If you can't do that, this Oracle page gives instructions for various web browsers on how to get Java working in the browser:

- [How do I enable Java in my web browser?](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

Note that the instructions need to be followed *by the end user*.